# How to modify facebook canvas page?

Tags: facebook, canvas, unity-game-engine, banner

I am making a game with Unity3d for facebook.
Is it possible to add anything else but the unity3d binary on the facebook canvas? Like background image, external advertisement banner etc. ?
Earlier there were more options, but nowadays you can only set you .unity3d file in the settings.

There are very limited options in facebook developer pages for modifying your canvas page, so I guess the page modification has to be done somewhere else?

I also tried Unity´s own webPlayerTemplate but that does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook canvas is just an iFrame meaning what ever you put in the web page of the game will be displayed in there.

You can add anything by editing the html page that comes as output from the webplayer build. Easy solution to try opening the html page in dreamweaver or similar and start adding elements and see if it comes in the output. Be cautious there are chances that the html content gets rendered behind the game.

PS: one problem with untiy's web player build it that it always gets rendered above the html contents in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer!

I forgot to mention this:
When making a game on facebook without "facebook SDK for Unity" you can set the canvas as a webpage.
Then the canvas can be modified with the html. I tried that and it works just fine.

But when your app is using facebook SDK you can only include .unity3d file URL and the html file is completely ignored.

PS: after some more studies it seems you can inject html commands with Application.ExternalEval()

basicly anywhere inside your unity project by:

string injection = "lines to be executed on your canvas page";
Application.ExternalEval(injection);